# deploying Springboot Microservice to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices

I have written a springboot microservice project and want to deploy it to aws.But i dont know which aws service i need  since i have dockerize the whole project and hope that to run the same as my local.

My docker-compose yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
      # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  dbmysql:
    container_name: dbmysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_USER: "admin"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: freelance
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"

    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/freelance_volume/_data

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /data/db

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
        - "9411:9411"



  eureka-server:
    image: eureka:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
    build:
      context: eureka-server/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=debug
      - spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411


  api-gateway:
    image: api-gateway:latest
    build:
      context: api-gateway/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411
      - log.level.root=info
      - spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=broker:29092


  notification:
    image: notification:latest
    build:
      context: notification/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - eureka-server
      - broker
      - zipkin
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
      - spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=broker:29092
      - spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411


  chatroom:
    image: chatroom:latest
    build:
      context: chatroom/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin

    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
      - spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411



  userjob:
    depends_on:
      - dbmysql
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin
    image: userjob:latest
    container_name: userjob
    build:
      context: userjob/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered #docker file path (. means root directory)
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://dbmysql:3306/freelance
    - spring.datasource.username=root
    - spring.datasource.password=password
    - log.level.root=info
    - spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=broker:29092
    - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    - spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.37.6
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-oss:8.5.2
    container_name: grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - prometheus:prometheus
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
```

The containers that i have used is actually quite a lot.I have checked out on aws ecs, but it seems that it is quite tedious to add all the containers in docker-compose yml as clusters and need manually config the environment variable.

And i have also checked on the AWS Cloud Formation,it seems that can directly handle on the docker-compose yml and deploy, but i dont know can it applied to the springboot microservice.Or is the best way is to deploy it to k8s and then use the eks.

Moreover on how to deploy the database and do i need to deploy on the other service like aws rds first.There are actually too less information on how to deploy spring microservice.Please give me some pointers if anyone familar with it.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/ it allows you to deploy to ECS using `docker compose` commands just as you would if you were running it locally

Comment: that's doc works ! thanks a lot